# Is coming up heads and coming up tails independent events in a single coin toss?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I just want to know, if a coin is tossed, the event of **getting heads(A)** and the event of **getting tails(B)** are independent to each other or not.

As, **P(A and B) is not equal to P(A) x P(B)** , can I conclude it is not a independent event?

But getting heads, how it can be dependent on getting tails? Also, getting tails, how it can be dependent on getting heads?

Comment: Getting heads means not getting tails, so they are dependent (at least if each of heads and tails have positive probability).  In symbols $P(A \cap B)=0$ and this is not $P(A)P(B)$ so long as both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are positive.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/380791/2958

Answer (score 3):

Consider a more general case, suppose you throw the coin for $n$ times, and let $X$ be the times you get face, $Y$ be the times you get tail. So you have

$$X+Y=n$$

Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables. For your case, just set $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a *single* coin toss, so they are for sure dependent events. Of course, if you get heads for this coin toss, it is not possible to also get tails on that same coin toss. So the events cannot be independent (information about one event occuring tells you about whether the other occurred).

They are also disjoint events, since they cannot occur together.